# How i can get a specific object of an ngrx store?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Nowadays my store is an object that inside have an `users` array of object:

```
{ "users": [ { "id": 1, "nome": "Renato Maionese", "cidade": "Franca" } ] }
```

This is the way that i get this data from my store:

```
constructor(
  private store: Store<{ count: number; userStates: Usuario }>
) {
  this.users$ = store.pipe(select('userStates'));
}
```

In my template i'm trying to make a *ngFor:

```
<tr *ngFor="let usuario of users$.users | async">
```

But i receive this warning:

> ERROR in src/app/pages/usuario/usuario.component.html:32:32 - error
>   TS2339: Property 'users' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

There's a way to get from my store only the user object, something like:

```
 this.users$ = store.pipe(select('userStates').users);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend your pipe, `select('userStates')` doesn't return data, it returns instructions how to get `userStates` once there's change in the store.

to map data there's `map` operator: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map

```js
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.users$ = store.pipe(
  select('userStates'),
  map(state => state.users), // now this.users$ returns users instead of state.
);
```

and now you can use it in the template without property access

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr *ngFor="let usuario of (users$ | async)?.users">
```

As mentioned below, you can use a selector. Another option is

```
this.users$ = store.pipe(
             select('userStates'),
             map(userstates => userstates.users));
```

Comment: This works but i think that this way i have a little repetead code (users.users), my curiosity is about grab only the object users inside my store, but thanks anyway